# How to configure XHProf on windows?

Tags: debugging

With the help of [Lorenzo Alberton](http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/) tutorial, i get XHProf installed for drupal 6 on linux server. Now i need to get it installed on windows but i found that XHProf cant be installed on windows. Additionally, at drupal.org [XHProf](http://drupal.org/project/XHProf), is available for drupal 7 onwards. If anyone has installed XHProf for drupal 6 on windows then please share.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only ***easy*** way I know of doing this on windows is with [quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart). You will need virtual box to run it, but it has xhprof & xdebug installed and pre-configured, along with many other goodies (editors, drush commands for quick setups of new projects, etc.

There is a [video here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=quickstart+xhprof&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXjgwhn_SnZc&ei=kdMKT_G5EMXd0QGW5qWRAg&usg=AFQjCNFUy2fw9WW5Qo2kDSjdOcJMrWHPdQ) explaining the procedure, and plenty of docs on the project page

Supports drupal 6 & 7. Great stuff, I have been using this every day for a good while now.

Hope that helps, good-luck!

Answer (score 9):

I just finally installed the `XHProf` profiler under `Windows7 x64 - PHP 5.3.x`. Assuming that you have a functional PHP environment, this checklist should work for you too:

- Download the pre-compiled [XHProf 0.10.3 - PHP 5.3 VC9 NTS](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-extensions/xhprof/file/details/xhprof-0103-for-php-53-vc9-nts.html) binary.
- Paste the downloaded `dll` file to PHP extensions directory.
  *(You can find the directory path in `extension_dir` directive of `php.ini` file.)*
- Append `extension=php_xhprof.dll` directive to the `php.ini`.
- Restart the web server and search`phpinfo()` output for `XHProf`. found? done!
- You might also want to use [`XHGui`](http://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof) fork instead of the built-in UI.

Comment: If any error throws related to dll try thread safe dll instead of non thread safe (nts) dll. Url to downlad: http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-extensions/xhprof.html

Comment: Before you start with the installation you have to know which `.dll` files are compatible with your environment, so find **(1)** if your php version is **Non-Thread-Safe (nts)** or **Thread-Safe (ts)**,  and **(2)**  its **Architecture**. These will help you to [download](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/xhprof/0.10.6/) the correct library: **(1)** `php -i|find "Thread"` **(2)** `php -i | find "Architecture"`

Answer (score 3):

See and follow this issue queue http://drupal.org/node/1011108. It does contain a link to download XHProf compiled as a .dll for Windows.

As for installation, see http://drupal.org/node/1421598.

Answer (score 2):

Please, know that the XHProf extension is **abandoned**.

There is an open source (and free) alternative that is maintained and will work in Windows and Linux called Tideways.

This extension (Tideways) is a FORK of XHprof so it produces compatible output and is able to work with all XHprof compatible tools.

All details explained here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/profiling-drupal-xhprof-uprofiler-tideways-php7-linux-and-windows

Download and enable the Tideways PHP like any other extension. Updated windows binaries to be found here (https://ci.appveyor.com/project/tideways/php-profiler-extension/history

After that my recommendation is to use the Tideways cloud service, or if you are bankrupt, use any do-it-yourself XHProf compatible tools such as XHGui.

Comment: What output Tideways it produces and where is it stored? I do not mean cloud version, only "drop in replacement" version of Tideways. Thanks.

Comment: xhprof has RISEN FROM THE GRAVE and released version 2.0 in Dec 2019 and has since had multiple releases, with Windows DLL's available for download. https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof